# custom window title half blocked by tabPageIndicator

Tags: android, android-layout

Im using JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator in my application and i also created custom window title. 
whem im trying ti run the app, i see that the custom title is half blocked by the rest of the activity.

http://postimg.org/image/c5w27rzj7/

this is part the main activity code :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new TubeFmAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    initEvents();
    }
```

android manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.TubeFM"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/WindowTitleTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.TubeFM.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="TubeFM"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                    android:exported="true"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="isLaunchableActivity" android:value="true"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.TubeFM.activities.VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="isLaunchableActivity" android:value="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

custom window title layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_search"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="5dip">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/text_search_background"
                android:hint="@string/search_artist"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_search">
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

activity theme:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.IconPageIndicator</item>
        <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget">
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.TabPageIndicator" parent="Widget">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/vpi__tab_indicator</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">22dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">22dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.TabPageIndicator
        </item>
        <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.TabPageIndicator" parent="Widget">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/vpi__dark_theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.IconPageIndicator" parent="Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">6dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok , so who face the same problem.
the solution is to make that activity use theme parent android:theme to all the relevant styles.

e.g :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="RidesTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">44dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@color/rides_window_title_bg</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SetRideTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">56dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```